# Manager Package - Lightning Pages for Standard Objects Missing

Tags: lightning

We are in the process of integrating Lighting Pages into our Managed Package.  Naturally we are using Lightning App Builder.

We have successfully enabled all of our Visual Force pages to be lighting aware, and have also created lightning specific pages for the rest of our objects.   In our package we also extend a number of Salesforce Standard Objects (Account, Asset, Case, Contact, Opportunity, Opportunity Line Item, Product, Quote, Quote Line Item), so have also created Lighting Page version for these objects.

However, when we perform a build of our Managed Package, our versions of the pages for these standard objects (listed above), are not being included in our Managed Package.

Is there a known restriction for these Standard Objects, along with a possible work around.   We cannot justify having to manually created Lighting Pages for every customer manually once our Package is installed.

Comment: How are you performing your build? Are your Lightning pages in your packaging org and included in the package?

Comment: Yes, the lightning pages are in our main development organization and we perform a standard managed package build.   Those pages which relate to our custom objects do become part of our package.  Our issue is that the build process is not including the Lightning Page layouts for the "Standard" objects.

Comment: Mark, I think there's some mechanisms there that are really important to your question. *Is* your main development org the packaging org? It sounds like it is not. If so, are the pages in the packaging org? What is the build process? (There is no standard). How does it identify what metadata to move to packaging?

Comment: Yes, the main development org is also the build/packaging org.   This is a managed package so the build process is completely under the salesforce build process.   Our package has been under continual development for over 7 years, and we are not provided with any explicit mechanism to indicate what metadata to move to the package.   When I indicate that this is in our main organization, I mean that this is not in a "Patch" development organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the new Lightning page to your package explicitly.

Select Add in the Packaging UI:

[image: Packaging UI]

then choose Lightning Page and select your new page:

[image: Packaging component selection]

Creating the component in the packaging org and performing Upload Package doesn't add the Lightning Page to your managed package; you'll need to select the component as above.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this.   This answer was exactly what we needed to add these standard pages to our package.   I reviewed all of the Lightning development information that we could locate, and it did not appear that this topic was mentioned.  Oh well, it is never possible to document every 'untypical' scenario.    Once again, thank you very much for your support.    This question may now be marked as 'Answered'.

Comment: @MarkLoChiano At your option, you can mark this answer (or any answer) as accepted by clicking the green check mark.